# Hibernate Positional parameter does not exist: 1 in query

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, nhibernate, postgresql

I'm trying to perform the following query, but receiving the exception bellow.

```
   List<Category> cats = session.createCriteria(Category.class).add(criterion).list();
    Map<Integer, CategoryNode> childNodes = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, CategoryNode>();
    for (Category cat : cats) {
        CategoryNode childNode = new CategoryNode();
        childNode.setCategory(cat);
        childNodes.put(cat.getId(), childNode);
    }
    StringBuilder questions = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.size(); ++i) {
        if (i != 0) {
            questions.append(", ");
        }
        questions.append("?");
    }


    Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
            "select c1.id, count(c2.id) "
            + "from CATEGORY c1 "
            + "left join CATEGORY c2 on c2.parentCategoryId = c1.id "
            + "where c1.id in (" + questions + ") "
            + "group by c1.id");

    int i = 0;

    for (Iterator<CategoryNode> it = childNodes.values().iterator(); i < childNodes.size(); ++i) {
        query.setLong(i + 1, it.next().getCategory().getId());
    }
```

> Positional parameter does not exist: 1 in query: select c1.id,
>   count(c2.id) from CATEGORY c1 left join CATEGORY c2 on
>   c2.parentCategoryId = c1.id where c1.id in (?) group by c1.id

Comment: Can you also post the next line of code? Is the variable `questions` a comma delimited string?

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks, yes questions is a a comma delimited string. I posted the entire query above. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Positional parameter starts from 0, so you may have to change the setting code to this

```
for (Iterator<CategoryNode> it = childNodes.values().iterator(); i < childNodes.size(); i++) {
    query.setLong(i, it.next().getCategory().getId());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like hibernate is expecting you to set a parameter because questions is a question mark:

```
where c1.id in (?)
```

Don't know much about hibernate but I guess you could set `questions` to actually contain a value for instance `questions = '1, 2, 3';` so that the query gets replaced by this:

```
where c1.id in (1, 2, 3)
```

Or maybe, which I think would be the appropiate way (and if hibernate supports this!) use the query:

```
where c1.id in (?)
```

And call a method from hibernate that will replace that ? with the parameter you set to it in php. Something like this maybe?

```
query.setString(0, questions);
```

Hope this helps, George.

Comment: Hi Mostacho, I'm using your second suggestion. I'll add the remainder of the query in my post. see above.